# Is there a multi-call equivalent for calls that aren't made to a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, ethers.js, nodejs, query

I have an array with a bunch of events. I get the block number from these events but I also need the block.timestamp which isnt returned in the event object, its returned by getting the block. So I am looking to do something like this:

```
  const getTimestamps = async (events) => {
  const ethcallProvider = new Provider(provider);
  await ethcallProvider.init();

  const contractCalls = events.map((event) =>
     provider.getBlock(event.blockNumber)
  );
  console.log(contractCalls);
  const results = await ethcallProvider.all(contractCalls);
  //console.log(results);
  return results;
};
```

I have hundreds of events so It would be helpful to be able to use something like multicall to be able to run all the getBlock functions in a single call. Or if theres a multicall libary out there that can do this that would also work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ethers.providers.JsonRpcBatchProvider`, its JS API is equivalent to the `JsonRpcProvider`. It simply batches the requests, so that multiple requests are sent together in a single network request, instead of separate network requests otherwise. You can find the docs for it [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/other/#JsonRpcBatchProvider).